# Karate - Can i send multiple dynamic data in Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

Below is the code :

```
Feature:
Background:

    * def Json = Java.type('Json')
    * def dq = new Json()
    * def result = dq.makeJson()
    * def Sku = dq.makeSku()

    Scenario Outline: id : <id> 
    * print '<id>'  #From result
    * print '<abc>' #From Sku


Examples:
|result|Sku|
```

The following is the output I need. Is it possible in Karate?

```
If i have id = {1,2} and abc = {3,4} i want output to be
        id = 1 and abc = 3
        id = 1 and abc = 4
        id = 2 and abc = 3
        id = 2 and abc = 4
```

Also can this be done for more than 2 variable inputs as well?

Comment: [plese consult help section on how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You usually get response proportional to effort you put into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the permutation logic yourself, build an array with the results.
Note that you can iterate over key-value pairs of a JSON using [`karate.forEach()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms)

Then either use a data-driven loop call (of a second feature file):

```
# array can be [{ id: 1, abc: 3 }, {id: 1, abc: 4 }] etc
* def result = call read('second.feature') array
```

Or a dynamic scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline:
* print 'id = <id> and abc = <abc>'
Examples:
| array |
```

Refer: 
https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features
https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline